# Cannot turn off password

Tags: 12.04, password, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ubuntu force users to create a password upon installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124773/why-does-ubuntu-force-users-to-create-a-password-upon-installation)

[Cannot authenticate without a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150181/cannot-authenticate-without-a-password) It did not fix my problem. If I create an admin account without password in the first place, what should I enter in place of the password? Also, how to perform administrative actions (such as `sudo` or downloading apps from Ubuntu Software Center) without password? How to remove the password entirely from my admin accounts?

Note: In Windows 7, when you do not set a password or remove the existing password for an administrator, that administrator can be used to authenticate without a password. *Leave the password blank and you can do anything*.

Comment: Short answer is that this is not Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/124773/why-does-ubuntu-force-users-to-create-a-password-upon-installation/124776#124776

Answer (score 3):

This is a security feature. If your administrator (or 'root') account didn't have a password, it would be ridiculously easy for a virus or other malicious program to cause a lot of trouble. So, really, you shouldn't try to disable it.

If you're doing a lot of stuff using `sudo` in one terminal, you can always use `sudo su -` to go into administrator mode in that terminal, and then omit `sudo` in that session.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a password! But if you want to avoid retyping it during a session (e.g. sudo) then try this

visudo

add the following line

```
 admin      ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Save and quit. This allows the user admin to run everything (sudo apt-get ...) without password

If you want that for a whole group of accounts, add them to a group, e.g. admin and visudo again this time with this line

```
%admin      ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This means any member of the admin GROUP is allowed to do everything without password.