# Password problems without setting one up

Tags: login, password, lock-screen

This might be a duplicate, but I didn't find any answer that fixes the problem.
I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS and did not create a password for logging in. Now, if I try to use "sudo" command or if my screen is locked, I'm asked for a password.
I tried the "System Settings" and "User Accounts" and I see a 5 digit password, which I have no idea what it is.
Has anyone seen this before? This is not that I forgot the password, I simply did not set one up.

Comment: AFAIK the installer *always* asks you to set a password - although it also allows you to opt not to use it for logins. Regardless, the solution is here [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu the system requires you to set a root (administrator) password upon install. ([See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124773/why-does-ubuntu-force-users-to-create-a-password-upon-installation)). If you have forgotten the administrator password you can always [reset it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). This would be the 2nd best option first being reinstalling Ubuntu and remembering the root password.

Comment: Thanks DnrDevil. I ended up re-installing Ubuntu. If I set up an admin password, then I had no idea what it was. Thanks for helping.

Comment: No problem glad as is working please remember to close the question by selecting the check mark